# How can i perform arthmetic opertion inside the data of array;

Tags: php, arrays

I want to perform the arithmetic operation on the data which is inside an array :

```
$add = 5

$array = [
    "price" => 7,
    "cg" => 9,
    "sg" => 9,
    "ts" => 150
];
```

I want to multiply `[rate] * $add` and then perform addition on `[cg] + [sg]`
and then I need perform the `[rate] * add / 100 * [cg] + [sg]`;

This is what I have tried is below  but doesn't work :

```
<?php
$arr1 = array_values($arr);
echo"<pre>";    
echo"<pre>";    
print_r($arr1[0]);
print_r($arr1[1]);

$totalrate = 0; 
foreach($arr1 as $value){   
    $totalrate = $totalrate + $value['rate'];
    print_r($totalrate);
}
?>
```

Comment: From where the `[rate]` come from?

Comment: It is come from the data base in array form

Comment: your explanation is not making any sense , can you please add expected output for understand properly. Thanks!

Comment: $ add = 5

(
    [price] => 7
    [cg] => 9
    [sg] => 9
    [ts] => 150
)           

 This is what I have in array form and I want to multiply [rate] * $add and then perform addition on [cg] + [sg]
and then

 I need perform the [rate] * add / 100 * [cg] + [sg];

Comment: is this your expected output?? i see this is already given in question as input

Comment: Have ypu understood that

Comment: _“Please Help I m new to php”_ - please explain what your actual problem is with getting what you want. The formula you mentioned is not overly complex, how the basic math operations work in PHP is something the manual or a beginner’s tutorial should be able to tell you … so, what exactly are you still missing here then?

Comment: So what you call `rate` all the time, is actually the `price` entry in the data you have shown? Please try and keep this stuff consistent, otherwise you are only adding more ambiguity than necessary.

Comment: @payzmall But your example array does not have a 'rate' property

Comment: yup that rate is price

Comment: @payzmall i think first you need to understand what is problem and then try to explain or solve your self. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding

Comment: this may help you -- $totalrate = $arr1[price] * $add/100 * $arr1[cg] + $arr1[sg]; no need to loop if you have single array you directly access through by associative index. [read](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

Comment: @payzmall if this help hepls, then i suggest to delete this question. this question not going to help this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you have :

```
$add = 5

$array = [
    "price" => 7,
    "cg" => 9,
    "sg" => 9,
    "ts" => 150
];
```

Now this is what you want to do :

> I want to multiply **[rate] * $add** and then perform addition on **[cg] + [sg]**
>   and then I need perform the **[rate] * add / 100 * [cg] + [sg]**;

Assuming what you call "rate" is the "price" in your array :

```
// [price] * $add
$first_calc  = $array['price'] * $add; 
// [cg] + [sg]
$second_calc = $array['cg'] + $array['sg']; 
// [price] * add / 100 * [cg] + [sg]
$third_calc  = $array['price'] * $add / 100 * $array['cg'] + $array['sg']
```

For the third calcul I think what you want is more **([price] * add) / 100 * ([cg] + [sg])** so it should be :

```
$third_calc  = $first_calc / 100 * $second_calc
```

Now, if what you have is one big array with multiple array inside that look like the `$array` I used for example, if the `$third_calc` is the `[rate]` you want and if what you want is add each `[rate]` to get your `$totalrate` :

```
$totalrate = 0; 
foreach($bigarray as $array){   
    // [price] * $add
    $first_calc  = $array['price'] * $add; 
    // [cg] + [sg]
    $second_calc = $array['cg'] + $array['sg']; 
    // [price] * add / 100 * [cg] + [sg]
    $third_calc  = $first_calc / 100 * $second_calc

    $totalrate += $third_calc;
}
```

The question is not clear so it is what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
    $add_value = 5;
    $array = array('price' => 7, 'cg' => 9, 'sg' => 9, 'ts' => 150);
    $rate = $add_value * $array['price'];
    $cg_plus_sg = $array['cg'] + $array['sg'];
    $result = ($rate * $add_value) / 100 * $cg_plus_sg;
    echo $result;
```